# Trying to save a 2012 macbook pro failing disk with ddrescue

Tags: data-recovery, macintosh, data, ddrescue

I have a Macintosh HD disk that failed suddenly (system would not boot anymore - diskutil complained about a problem with the B-tree. Tried various diskutil commands in the past without success) which I tried to salvage using ddrescue in the last days (I only have linux-based computers at the moment) - using command:

```
ddrescue -f -r0 -n -d /dev/sdc /storage/macos.img /storage/macos_recovery.log
```

The process ended today after quite a while and showed a very disappointing output
[image: ddrescue]
It's the stock 500gb HDD HFS+ disk from the 2012 macbook. The first row is almost all OK so I thought I could save some important files there (they are usually < 100kb so maybe there's hope ?).
So here's what I tried after that on the img file:

1 - Tried a photorec on it - cannot find anything except useless txt files

2 - Tried testdisk on it - reports a None-partitionned disk (I set it as EFI GPT anyways) and finds random HFS+ partitions everywhere.

3 - Trying gparted partition recovery at the moment

So here are my questions:

- The disk is 500gb and the output img file is 931G. How is that possible ?
- What may cause that kind of damage pattern ? I saw various patterns (usually linear - like a scratch on the disk) on stackX sites but never regular waves like that. Could that be fixable ?
- Where could I find the original informations about that 2012 macbook disk, in order to manually rebuild the partition map (informations about where the recovery hd/macintosh hd partitions starts/ends for example) ?

  - Any other ideas on how to recover anything from that mess ?

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT - Output of smartctl -a**

```
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-5.3.6-xanmod5] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Hitachi/HGST Travelstar 5K750
Device Model:     APPLE HDD HTS547550A9E384
Serial Number:    J2260051KWP00D
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 641f6db5d
Firmware Version: JE3AD70F
User Capacity:    500 107 862 016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Sun Oct 27 09:14:48 2019 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (   45) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 139) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   049   049   062    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 625027130
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   176   176   033    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       14740
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   001   001   005    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 597
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   077   077   000    Old_age   Always       -       10420
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       13180
160 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       65545
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       3813930958943
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   019   019   000    Old_age   Always       -       810746
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   222   222   000    Old_age   Always       -       27 (Min/Max 4/46)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   050   050   000    Old_age   Always       -       1351
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       58752
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   036   036   000    Old_age   Always       -       8589951106

SMART Error Log Version: 1
Warning: ATA error count 65535 inconsistent with error log pointer 4

ATA Error Count: 65535 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 65535 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10410 hours (433 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 38 e8 1c 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x001ce838 = 1894456

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 58 38 e8 1c 40 00   1d+22:15:55.577  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+22:15:55.576  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00   1d+22:15:55.576  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+22:15:55.573  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+22:15:55.573  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 65534 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10410 hours (433 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 38 e8 1c 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x001ce838 = 1894456

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 80 38 e8 1c 40 00   1d+22:15:55.186  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+22:15:55.186  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00   1d+22:15:55.186  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+22:15:55.183  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+22:15:55.183  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 65533 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10410 hours (433 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 10 38 e8 1c 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x001ce838 = 1894456

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 10 48 38 e8 1c 40 00   1d+22:15:54.805  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 38 28 3c 84 40 00   1d+22:15:54.799  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 28 3a 84 40 00   1d+22:15:54.765  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 f8 28 30 42 06 40 00   1d+22:15:54.762  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 f8 20 30 41 06 40 00   1d+22:15:54.760  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 65532 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10410 hours (433 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 38 e8 1c 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x001ce838 = 1894456

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 98 38 e8 1c 40 00   1d+22:14:48.581  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+22:14:48.580  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00   1d+22:14:48.580  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+22:14:48.577  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+22:14:48.576  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 65531 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10410 hours (433 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 10 38 e8 1c 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x001ce838 = 1894456

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 10 28 38 e8 1c 40 00   1d+22:14:48.189  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 20 28 3c 84 40 00   1d+22:14:48.183  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 f0 28 3a 84 40 00   1d+22:14:48.150  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 f8 e8 30 42 06 40 00   1d+22:14:48.147  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 f8 e0 30 41 06 40 00   1d+22:14:48.145  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

**EDIT 2**

I noted that the HDD works flawlessly - without any noises - in the green parts (good sectors) but start doing a weird noise on the possibly bad sectors (like a repetitive muffled/muted knocking and some high-pitched "older-hdd" read noise). I opened the disk yesterday and the top plate looks perfect, and the heads returns to the stop position. Nothing looks burnt or displaced. Any ideas on the source of this noise ?

Comment: do you have something like `smartctl -a` for the disk, or system error log messages, `dmesg`? can you rule out cable issues and other intermittent errors? did you try doing another pass and see if that gets more data?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Edited with smartctl output. Got lots of read errors in the dmesg (but green blocks in the ddrescue reads properly) so I had to reduce the timeout for read errors in order for ddrescue to complete. Multiple computers tried reading the disk (via USB HDD reader and now its wired by SATA directly). Multiple cables tried - intermittent errors I do not know how to test that.
The situation did not worsen in the last years. Disk shows the same bad sectors. Another pass does not help

Comment: I think getting the answer for second question is the *key* to recover data: bad sector pattern looks like a pure mechanical issue (maybe *head*); can you disassemble plate and mount it on a known working HD?

Comment: That's what I think as well. My next step is reassembling the HDD plate(s) in a similar HDD. Since this is risky I think excluding all the software-based solutions and finding a good diagnostic may be better first ?

Comment: Doing a platter transplant without professional tools is almost certain to destroy your hard drive.  A simpler operation (replacing the hard drive's cover with a piece of glass) used to be popular among the modding community, but I haven't heard of a successful window mod in 15 years, and even then, a 50% failure rate was normal.  Hard drives have only gotten more sensitive to dust since then.